# add a property to asp.net user control and display as attribute on output html

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

my (TextBox user control) Date property:

```
    [Category("Behavior"),
    Description("convert the current text to DateTime")]
    public DateTime? MyDate
    {
        get
        {                
            return ChangeDate();
        }
        set
        {
            Text = ToDateString(value);
        }
    }
```

and in asp.net:

```
<my:XTextBox ID="XTextBox1" runat="server"></my:XTextBox>
```

i want to see this property like **Text** Property on output:

```
<input name="XTextBox1" type="text" id="XTextBox1" MyDate="2013-10-11" />
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

so in code behind i can access to **MyDate** like this?!

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = XTextBox1.MyDate;
}
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: What part of your code is not working?

Comment: the html output(input) not have attribute `MyDate`!

Answer (score 1):

You can add an attribute to the user control like below:

**XTextBox.ascx(UserControl markup):**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="XTextBox.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserControlTest.XTextBox" %>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbText" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

**XTextBox.ascx.cs (UserControl code):**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace UserControlTest
{
    public partial class XTextBox : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {

        [Category("Behavior"), Description("convert the current text to DateTime")]
        public DateTime? MyDate
        {
            get
            {
                return ChangeDate();
            }
            set
            {               
                tbText.Text =  ToDateString(value);
            }
        }

        private string ToDateString(DateTime? dt )
        {
            return dt.HasValue ? ((DateTime)dt).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        }

        private DateTime? ChangeDate()
        {
            DateTime dt;
            if (DateTime.TryParse(tbText.Text, out dt))
            {
                tbText.Attributes.Add("MyDate", tbText.Text);
                return dt;
            }
            tbText.Attributes.Add("MyDate", "");
            return null;
        }
    }        
}
```

And use the control in your page:

**TestForm.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="UserControlTest.TestForm" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/XTextBox.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="XTextBox" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <uc1:XTextBox runat="server" id="XTextBox" />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**TestForm.aspx.cs:**

```
using System;

namespace UserControlTest
{
    public partial class TestForm : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = XTextBox.MyDate.HasValue? ((DateTime)XTextBox.MyDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : "";
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){ }
    }
}
```

**How to test:**

First time when the test Page loads, usercontrol's `MyDate` is null. So the label in the test form will not display anything. In the markup you can see the attribute is null:

```
<input type="text" mydate="" id="XTextBox_tbText" name="XTextBox$tbText">
```

Type valid date in the textbox in test form and click the button. The label should show the date and in the markup you can see the `MyDate` attribute.

[image]